# Single page app, permalinks and ngView?

Tags: data-binding, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

This is my current setup, with each column being represented by a controller:

```
<navbar></navbar>
[column1] [column2] [column3]
<footer></footer>
```

Additionally each column has a bit of information (one or more variables and objects) which when modified, need to be propagated across to its neighbour.

Presently I share these variables by using a factory and injecting that into the relevant controller(s).

Now I want to permalink variable values, e.g.:

```
http://localhost/column1/vars?var1=2&var2='hi'
                /column2/ls1=%7B%27c%27%3A+1%2C+%27f%27%3A+%27b%27%7D
                /column3/...
```

This should also allow me to remove my factories.

**What's the best way to achieve this setup, e.g.: are `ngView`s the answer?**

Comment: Does this information need to live in a permalink or could it live in a controller that is the parent to your tabs?

Comment: Would like permalink, as the configurable information (and search queries) should be bookmarkable. There are URL length issues to consider, so might end up using a cookie or LocalStorage; but preferably the URL length is long enough for my purposes.

Comment: Are these parameters known upfront or are you creating them on the fly? I ask because there are some limitations for optional parameters (the stuff after ?) in the angular router.

Comment: There are a constant number of parameters; all initialised to their respective data-type.

Comment: You should look at ui-router then with ui-view which will allow for multiple control areas on a page and tracking of nested state transitions. See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.

Comment: Thanks, taking a look. Would also be great if you could throw in a little code and write it up as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the angular-ui teams ui-router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for this to keep track of what is effectively a set of optional parameters. To do this your code would look something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script>
    <script src="angular-ui-states.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="" ng-click="transition('foo', {var1: 'hello', var2: 'world'})">Go to Foo</a></li>
      <li><a ng-href="#/bar?var1={{bazVars.var1}}&var2={{bazVars.var2}}">Go to Bar</a></li>
      <li><a href="" ng-click="transitionLocation('baz', {var1: 'sionara', var2: 'world', var3: 'meh'})">Go to Baz</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/bah">Go to Bah</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div ui-view></div>
    <pre>
      {{$stateParams}}
    </pre>
  </body>

</html>
```

with a stateprovider setup to accept these optional parameters:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.state'])
  .config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
          .state('foo',
          {
            url: '/foo?var1&var2',
            template: '<h1>Foo</h1>', 
            controller: 'subCtrl'
          })
          .state('bar',
          {
            url: '/bar?var1&var2',
            template: '<h1>Bar</h1>', 
            controller: 'subCtrl'
          })
          .state('baz',
          {
            url: '/baz?var1&var2&var3',
            template: '<h1>Baz</h1>', 
            controller: 'subCtrl'
          })
          .state('bah',
          {
            url: '/bah?var1&var2&var3',
            template: '<h1>Bah</h1>', 
            controller: 'subCtrl'
          });
    }])
    .run(['$stateParams', '$rootScope', function($stateParams, $rootScope){
      $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams
    }]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $state, $location) {
  $scope.bazVars = {
    var1: 'goodbye',
    var2: 'world'
  }
  $scope.transition = function(name, options){
    $state.transitionTo(name, options);
  }
  $scope.transitionLocation = function(name, options){
    $location.path('/' + name);
    for(key in options){
      $location.search(key, options[key]); 
    }
    console.log($location.url());
  }
});

app.controller('subCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams){
  console.log($stateParams);
})
```

Working plunker of the above: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZVLApU92MVdIhlovailY?p=preview

Note that ui-router allows for nested states using a dot notation as well so you can keep track of sub parameters of your page with this same mechanism (see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views).

Comment: Thanks, but your example doesn't seem to work. E.g.: clicking "bar" shows vars in URL, but nothign else does: http://run.plnkr.co/FQNyT91vsGlCqdk8/#/bar?var1=goodbye&var2=world

Comment: Actually it was working however the reference to # in the href of foo and baz was then replacing the url immediately after the transition. Sorry about that, fixed in the example and the plunker.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the requirement here all that well...

One thing is sharing parameters and sharing them among controllers... But I am not sure I understand your URLs entirely...

What I am most curious about is the presence of "Column1, Column2 and Column3" in the url? what is the need for those?...

Here is a little plunker to see if I have just gotten close to understand part of the idea:
 - http://plnkr.co/edit/ZkaANVq5tCdLKWqHFa16?p=preview

(Using https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-routing)

It really just propagates all variables into a link for the same "state"...

Note: I Choose a more advanced routing solution than Angulars ngRoute module, but in reality, for this use-case I don't think you need anything more advanced than the basic router... but it does ofc. have the advantage that you won't have to change at a later point if you suddenly find your self needing nested views, ability to filter parameters etc.